# Redirect subdomain to /folder

Tags: apache, unix, config

I want to redirect the sub-domain webmail to /roundcube for that domain. This have to work for all virtual hosts in apache.

Example:

webmail.example.com must point to [www.]example.com/roundcube

How is this possible? The server where it has to be done is configured with direct admin :S

Answer (score 3):

`mod_rewrite` is your friend.

Try something like this in your Apache `VirtualHost` configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^webmail\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule   ^webmail\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$  http://www.$1.$2/roundcube  [R=permanent]
```

...and configure DNS to point `webmail.example.com` to the same server as `www.example.com`.